# NextJS and i18n to generate static HTML page at build time

Tags: next.js, internationalization

I'm creating a simple Nextjs website with i18n for 2 languages.

the structure is more or less:

```
page.js
layout.js
[lang]
| page.js
```

where page.js is something like:

```
const Page = ({ params }) => {
  const l10n = getTranslation(params.lang);
  return <div>{l10n.title}</div>;
}
```

here the getTranslation implementation

```
import en from './en.json';
import it from './it.json';

export const getTranslation_ = (locale) => {
  if (locale === 'it') {
    return it;
  }
  if (locale === 'en') {
    return en;
  }
};
```

At build time the compiler marks the `[lang]/page.js` component as dynamic due to the fact that it lays inside a "slug" folder. This force me to deploy the site in a node.js environment.

But being my site only in two language, I'd prefer to pre-render each l10n at build time inside a specific folder named with the  '[lang]' placeholder replaced by the language code (like, 'en', 'de', etc) and deploy a simple static HTML website.

Is that possible with NextJS? Should I use some extra library?